# Grid not working after updating to Boostrap 3. Content is still stacking

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gridview, grid, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new at this... I'm attempting to use the bootstrap grid system. Before I changed to 3 it was fine, but when I changed over, the grid stopped working. I'm attempting to put a logo at the top with some options for social aspects to the right of it in its own respective grids.

But it ends up just putting the new text?content under the logo. No grid. Here's the code :

```
<div class = "container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="Red_Feather_Rogers_supplyf.gif">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

To clarify I do end the container div at the end of the body.Also the text is just temporary. the goal is to add buttons for social media.

Comment: If the above code is exactly what you are using, then you are missing a closing div tag.  That could be your problem.

Comment: the above is code perfect except the issue of closing tage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't close the div tag, just add the close tag at the end.

```
</div>
```